# What is the simplest way to create a Python .exe that works on a machine without Python installed?

Tags: python, py2exe, software-distribution

I've created a python application but I want to be able to give it to customers who don't have python on their machine. Is this possible?

I assume you'd have to create an internal python environment. It's a small application though, meaning it uses only a few imported libraries, so even if all the libraries were downloaded it shouldn't be that large.

Comment: I recommend you to read a bit about and try to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), it is really simple to use because it automates the process of finding dependencies.

Comment: Also, another option is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: @maccinza that is beautiful! It's so much simpler thank you!